# Why does my daemon only run one instance?

Tags: linux, daemon

I'm currently using the `skeleton` in `/etc/init.d` to start a daemon when my computer boots. I need the daemon to run three instances. In my skeleton, I have changed the code in the start function to:

```
cd dir1 ; start-stop-daemon -b --start --quiet --pidfile ${PIDFILE}1 --exec $DAEMON -- \
                  $DAEMON_ARGS \
                  || return 2 ;
cd dir2 ; start-stop-daemon -b --start --quiet --pidfile ${PIDFILE}2 --exec $DAEMON -- \
                  $DAEMON_ARGS \
                  || return 2 ;
cd dir3 ; start-stop-daemon -b --start --quiet --pidfile ${PIDFILE}3 --exec $DAEMON -- \
                  $DAEMON_ARGS \
                  || return 2 ;
```

Because my DAEMON variable points to a binary that I control, I know without a shadow of a doubt that each instance at least runs for a bit. But when the system comes up finally, I can only ever see one instance of the process running. I also looked at the man page of start-stop-daemon and it is not supposed to kill an already running instance if --pidfile is specified. I am also using -b, and I have tested my daemon script where I execute it directly with `run.sh start`. After this, I can see three processes running as I expect.

How do I get all three instances to stay?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of having a pidfile is generally to block launching of several instances. In your case, you actually want three, but you have assigned them the same pidfile.

> --pidfile ${PIDFILE}1

Try changing the other two to

> --pidfile ${PIDFILE}2

and

> --pidfile ${PIDFILE}3

EDIT:
Here is an example how/why this should work:

```
root# cat > foobar.sh << EOF
#!/bin/sh
sleep 60
EOF
root# start-stop-daemon -b -m --pidfile /var/run/p1 --exec /home/qwerty/foobar.sh --start
root# start-stop-daemon -b -m --pidfile /var/run/p2 --exec /home/qwerty/foobar.sh --start
root# start-stop-daemon -b -m --pidfile /var/run/p3 --exec /home/qwerty/foobar.sh --start
root# cat /var/run/p1 /var/run/p2 /var/run/p3
6307
6316
6320
root# ps auxgww | grep foobar
root      6307  0.0  0.0   4440   656 ?        S    00:09   0:00 /bin/sh /home/qwerty/foobar.sh
root      6316  0.0  0.0   4440   656 ?        S    00:09   0:00 /bin/sh /home/qwerty/foobar.sh
root      6320  0.0  0.0   4440   656 ?        S    00:09   0:00 /bin/sh /home/qwerty/foobar.sh
root      6330  0.0  0.0  11740   936 pts/0    S+   00:09   0:00 grep --color=auto foobar
```

Comment: Sorry, no I actually already have that in my script and it didn't fix it :/ I had thought of that earlier and tried it.

Comment: Strange, it should have worked out for you. Are PIDFILE and DAEMON set up correctly? They should be absolute paths, e.g. /var/run/mydaemon1.pid and /usr/sbin/mydaemon.  Now, seeing that `cd dir2` indicates that they are relative.

Comment: No, they are absolute. I apologize for my example, I basically cut it right out of the code and edited it poorly.

Comment: Edited the answer with a working example. While creating it, I also see that you don't have the -m flag, that you likely want since you have the -b.

Comment: The example may work in your shell, but it's not the same when it starts up. I wrote that I can test the sample manually; it works fine the way it had been before I ever tried to edit it - but only when I run it in my shell. I can only ever see one process instance running after startup.

Comment: Note that the "--make-pidfile" that you found working is the same as the "-m" I had in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know what your DAEMON does, I going to attempt a guess and try to provide an answer starting with the word, If.

If your DAEMON app has networking capability and it uses TCP, it will need a PORT. Since TCP is connection based, you cannot use the same port over again if the DAEMON is listening using that port. If you try to, it's possible that your starting a new instance of that DAEMON and one is already using the PORT, your new instance might be crashing or your previous instance might be crashing.

If that is the case, an alternative might be, if your DAEMON has the option to pass in an alternate port to listen on, your can listen on different ports. However, remember that any endpoints attempting to send to it will need to know what ports it should send to. Plus you will have to open up those ports in your IPTables or what ever else you might be using to allow data to get to your DAEMON.

If it's based on UDP, and your doing the software development for your DAEMON, there's more flexibility.

Comment: There isn't any networking in it. Just a program that is supposed to execute in the background and use a couple files.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, the following ended up being as solution:

```
cd /tmp/dir1 && start-stop-daemon -b --start --quiet --pidfile ${PIDFILE}1 --make-pidfile --exec ${DAEMON}1 -- \
          $DAEMON_ARGS ;
cd /tmp/dir2 && start-stop-daemon -b --start --quiet --pidfile ${PIDFILE}2 --make-pidfile --exec ${DAEMON}2 -- \
          $DAEMON_ARGS ;
cd /tmp/dir3 && start-stop-daemon -b --start --quiet --pidfile ${PIDFILE}3 --make-pidfile --exec ${DAEMON}3 -- \
          $DAEMON_ARGS ;
```

I had neglected to take the || return 2 part off at the end of each command, and I hadn't know what start-stop-daemon was returning because it was being executed by the system on startup.